# Login shell will not open at boot, only opens when I logoff then login

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, zsh, autostart

I am using arch linux. My default shell is /bin/zsh and I want it to open and hang around at startup(after login).

I have tried adding it through the "Session and Startup" GUI many times which didn't work. I have also made and enabled a service for systemd twice now with no success. I have made a crontab for it which only succeeded in getting the terminal to run at startup but it instantly closed in a couple of seconds. I have made a few .sh scripts and put them in the correct spots, but these also failed. I expected one of these methods to work, and it seems I have tried everything. Maybe I am doing something wrong or I am forgetting something. Any suggestions?

I edited /etc/zsh/zprofile and added the line "zsh." Now ,the login shell only opens when I log out and log back in. When I reboot the system and login it does not start. How should I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what exactly you did. For example, copy&paste the `systemd` service configuration, the contents of the "few .sh scripts" you made and tell us what "the correct spots" are. A line `zsh` in `/etc/zsh/zprofile` is wrong. I guess there is a misunderstanding on your side. A shell is not a window in a graphical desktop environment like `CMD` in Windows. In UNIX/Linux the shell is cleanly separated from the terminal (emulation). You have to start a terminal program of your choice. This should automatically run an instance of your login shell.